# Adding conditional zeroes to a ssn style number in Excel

Tags: excel, string

Trying to add conditional zeroes to a ssn style number in Excel.

```
1234-1234-12 -> 12340-1234-12
12345-123-12 -> 12345-1230-12
12345-1234-1 -> 12345-1234-10
12345-1234-12 -> do nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse each part and then make sure it is the desired number of numbers and concatenate it back together:

```
=LEFT(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)&"00000",5)&"-" & LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1)&"0000",4)&"-"&LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1,LEN(A1))&"00",2)
```

[image]

Comment: Damn you're so fast. You are not even giving chance to other. :)

Comment: 35 more points and I am done for today. @ManishChristian  Need to go help my sister build her house.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a VBA answer to complement @scottcraner's excellent answer:

```
Function ExpandSSN(s As String) As String
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim part As String
    A = Split(s, "-")
    part = Trim(A(0))
    A(0) = part & String(5 - Len(part), "0")
    part = Trim(A(1))
    A(1) = part & String(4 - Len(part), "0")
    part = Trim(A(2))
    A(2) = part & String(2 - Len(part), "0")
    ExpandSSN = Join(A, "-")
End Function
```

Put the above code in a standard code module. Then enter the formula e.g.  `=ExpandSSN(A1)` in B1 and drag down:

[image]